# Why does my test run in <1 second in single execution but 20+ seconds in maven build?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am working on a project with several spring-boot-based integrationtests that take ~5 Minutes to run in total. Upon trying to reduce this runtime i noticed that one very small and simple test takes ~20 seconds. When run "alone" it takes less than a second, which is what I would have expected.

The other tests are all integrationtests with annotations like:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@MockBean(value = SomeBean.class)
@MockMvcTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = someInitializer.class)
```

But the test in question has no annotations like this, requires no application context and *should* go through smoothly and quickly according to my understanding. It looks something like this:

```java
public class SomeUnitTest{

    @Test
    public void testObjectOfClass(){
        SomeClass someClass= new SomeClass ("1", "2", "3", "4");

        SomeClass.assertThat(someClass).hasId("1-2-3-4");        
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why the tests behave like this. Even if I can't change it I would really apreciate to understand what's going on.

Comment: You forgot to include the test itself in your question. Without it, there is not much chance that anybody will be able to answer.

Comment: This is hard to answer, because "It looks something like this" may hide the actual problem you are hitting.

Comment: Is the time lag during maven sorting itself out, or executing the actual test?  Which maven plugin are you using to execute the test?

Comment: The unit test really does not do anything more than that. The class that is being tested is plain java with some lombok annotations. That´s it. I can't show the actual code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before where the JUnit runner is timing it incorrectly.

I had a test that would run sub-second on its own but slow in a full test run. It would run immediately before a test with a bunch of setup with plugins & @BeforeAll steps. After digging into it, I found that the timer was not switching to this next test class until after the setup was completed.

It's possible you're seeing the same thing if the other tests have lots of pre-test setup.

EDIT: `@BeforeAll` definitely gets timed poorly.

```
public class TestA {
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}

public class TestB {
    @BeforeAll
    public static void before() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}

public class TestC {
    @BeforeAll
    public static void before() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems very plausible. The following tests do have alot of setup with @BeforeAll. So this might very well be the reason.